# category search not showing up in web part list

Tags: 2010, web-part

When i try to add a standard Search web part to my home page i cannot see the category search. In one of my site collections it is available, but in the other site collection it is not. Now i know it is propably something i have to activate, but i have been looking a lot now and can't seem to find it. Below is an image to further explain my problem.

Thanks in advance!

[Image http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/3809/errorbq.png](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/3809/errorbq.png)

**Edit** So the answer below is correct, the reason why i did not find it by myself because I was logged in as a user with full control but not site colelction admin. So i did not see this option, so for future reference, don't make the same mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your *site collection features* and ckeck the **Search Server Web Parts** Feature is activated.

> Search Server Web Parts
>
> This feature uploads all web parts required for Search Center.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ofcourse this is the answer, as i said i just couldn't find it anymore, thanks!